# How fast are Azure Storage changes propagated to instances?

Tags: windows, concurrency, azure, cloud, azure-storage

Suppose I have several role instances and one instance writes to Azure Storage (blob, tables or queue - whatever). How fast will other instances be able to see and read those changes?

Comment: Aren't storages different entities altogether? Thus, as soon as one instance finishes writing to a storage, the other instances should be able to see it.

Comment: @Alex R. Does this mean it will see it immediately or will there be some delay?

Comment: @sharptooth As Alex R. and Steve say, the Azure storage services and the code you deploy i.e. your role instances are different entities. There is no automatic synching whatsoever between your role instances and the storage services that is done by the Azure infrastructure. So, any interaction between your code residing in the role instances and the Azure storage services is explicit and under your control. E.g. role instance A writes a file to blob storage, role instance B polls blob storage for changes every 2 seconds = 2 sec change propagation delay (not considering network latency).

Comment: @sharptooth: Like what others have already mentioned. Think of the Azure storage as a common resource (e.g. a file or database), which multiple instances of the same application use. Once instance #1 finishes writing to that common resource, instance #2 can access that newly-written data right away.

Comment: @tishon: Okay, suppose the "reader" code polls for changes in an endless loop without any delay (`while( true ) { pollForChanges();}`) - will it see changes immediately after they've been submitted by the "writer"?

Comment: Yes... but I made a mistake in some polling code I wrote and ended up with an extra $500 in storage transaction costs several months in a row. So don't poll as fast as possible :)

Comment: @Steve: Yes, I understand that I shouldn't poll like that. My question was exactly about how fast instances will see recent changes. Could you please update you answer with details about that aspect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no propagation of data from Azure Storage to Role Instances. When you request or persist data from storage you're making an OData request over the network in the background to the Azure Storage services.

Because the data is stored in a central location there is only one authority for the information. The instant that authority is updated, clients will immediately receive the updated data when it is requested.

Comment: Windows Azure storage is consistent, so as soon as the write has finished (the storage service replies with a success code), it's available to be read.