# Why would I get "The specified blob does not exist" after the blob has been uploaded?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm reviewing logs of my Azure web service and see a logged exception:

```
The specified blob does not exist.
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.RequestWithRetry.RequestWithRetrySyncImpl[TResult](
       ShouldRetry retryOracle, SynchronousTask`1 syncTask)
  // my code calling CloudBlob.DownloadToStream() here
```

and the service structure is designed such that the code that encountered the exception is only being run after the blob has first been uploaded to storage.

This code has been working for months and worked just fine for thousands of blobs. Now it encountered the exception above and it doesn't seem to be reproducible. The most surprising thing is that the blob claimed "not existing" in this exception is currently in the storage and looks just as fine as all other blobs.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6517352/57428) once a blob has been uploaded it should be accessible to anyone (with respect to access restrictions of course) immediately so the subsequent download should just succeed.

So it looks like some weird problem. I'm using Azure SDK 1.6 if that matters.

What was I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Does your blob name contain any special characters (like "&", "%" etc.) which needs to be escaped?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri: Absolutely not.

Comment: Sorry, more questions. Does this happen with a particular blob or happens randomly with any blob. What happens when you try and access the blob via web browser (by pasting blob URI -- and making blob container public)? Do you still get that 404 error? You're right that once a blob is uploaded successfully, it is available immediately.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri: I can't reproduce it - the blob is now fetched okay. It happened once in like several months and with one blob only.